# Adapting XSLT to exclude attribute from comparison before merge, but still use the value

Tags: xslt

I am having trouble adapting an XSLT to handle some extra attribute rules/logic.

I have 'general' and 'specific' XML files that I am merging with this XSLT:
http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html

Source Files

general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<phone-settings e="2">
<language perm="RW">English</language>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="">0</codec1_name>
<codec1_name idx="2" perm="">0</codec1_name>
</phone-settings>
</settings>
```

specific.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<phone-settings e="2">
<language perm="RW">German</language>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="R">8</codec1_name>
</phone-settings>
</settings>
```

- XML documents are merged, specific replaces general.
- If the attributes & their values match exactly the specific data is used.

To this point the transformation works well, but I have to make adjustments:

- Some elements have a 'idx' attribute which identifies that element uniquely
- Some elements have a 'perm' attribute which determines if it is read/write by the user.

If the same element exists in both source files, but with a different 'perm' attribute, the XSLT considers it unique and a duplicate element is introduced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<phone-settings e="2">
<language perm="RW">German</language>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="">0</codec1_name>
<codec1_name idx="2" perm="">0</codec1_name>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="R">8</codec1_name>
</phone-settings>
</settings>
```

Here is the XSLT template that handles the single-node comparision:

```
<xslt:template name="m:compare-nodes">
   <xslt:param name="node1" />
   <xslt:param name="node2" />
   <xslt:variable name="type1">
      <xslt:apply-templates mode="m:detect-type" select="$node1" />
   </xslt:variable>
   <xslt:variable name="type2">
      <xslt:apply-templates mode="m:detect-type" select="$node2" />
   </xslt:variable>

   <xslt:choose>
      <!-- Are $node1 and $node2 element nodes with the same name? -->
      <xslt:when test="$type1='element' and $type2='element' and local-name($node1)=local-name($node2) and namespace-uri($node1)=namespace-uri($node2) and name($node1)!=$dontmerge and name($node2)!=$dontmerge">
         <!-- Comparing the attributes -->
         <xslt:variable name="diff-att">
            <!-- same number ... -->
            <xslt:if test="count($node1/@*)!=count($node2/@*)">.</xslt:if>
            <!-- ... and same name/content -->
            <xslt:for-each select="$node1/@*">
               <xslt:if test="not($node2/@* [local-name()=local-name(current()) and namespace-uri()=namespace-uri(current()) and .=current()])">.</xslt:if>
            </xslt:for-each>
         </xslt:variable>
         <xslt:choose>
            <xslt:when test="string-length($diff-att)!=0">!</xslt:when>
            <xslt:otherwise>=</xslt:otherwise>
         </xslt:choose>
      </xslt:when>

      <!-- Other nodes: test for the same type and content -->
      <xslt:when test="$type1!='element' and $type1=$type2 and name($node1)=name($node2) and ($node1=$node2 or ($normalize='yes' and normalize-space($node1)= normalize-space($node2)))">=</xslt:when>

      <!-- Otherwise: different node types or different name/content -->
      <xslt:otherwise>!</xslt:otherwise>
   </xslt:choose>
</xslt:template>
```

I can exclude the 'perm' attribute from the match by doing this:

```
<!-- ... and same name/content -->
<xslt:for-each select="$node1/@* [name(.)!='perm']">
```

That solves the duplicate element issue, unfortunately it also means that the value for that attribute in the specific XML file - 'R' in this case is not merged:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<phone-settings e="2">
<language perm="RW">German</language>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="">8</codec1_name>
<codec1_name idx="2" perm="">0</codec1_name>
</phone-settings>
</settings>
```

How can I exclude the 'perm' attribute from the uniqueness test while still ensuring its value in the specific XML file is used in the merge?

The desired result from merging the two example files at the top is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<phone-settings e="2">
<language perm="RW">German</language>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="R">8</codec1_name>
<codec1_name idx="2" perm="">0</codec1_name>
</phone-settings>
</settings>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution and recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

> I can exclude the 'perm' attribute
>   from the match by doing this:
>
> `<!-- ... and same name/content -->`
>
> `<xslt:for-each select="$node1/@*[name(.)!='perm']">`
>
> That solves the duplicate element
>   issue, unfortunately it also means
>   that the value for that attribute in
>   the specific XML file - 'R' in this
>   case is not merged
>
> How can I exclude the 'perm' attribute
>   from the uniqueness test while still
>   ensuring its value in the specific XML
>   file is used in the merge?

**From a brief reading of the quite complex merge-code, it seems that you can achieve your goal by changing this** (at line 190):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$first1/@*" />
```

**with this**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$first2/@*" />
```

**Do note**: A better solution than what you are currently doing is to introduce a new global paramere, say `$ignore-attributes-in-comparison` and specify as value a space-separated string with the names of all attributes that should be ignored in a node comparison.

Comment: Thanks, with that change the simple examples I provided now merge correctly. Unfortunately it doesn't work when there are additional elements, for example with this new specific.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<phone-settings e="2">
<language perm="RW">German</language>
<user_name idx="1" perm="R">abc</user_name>
<user_host idx="1" perm="R">something.somewhere</user_host>
<codec1_name idx="1" perm="R">8</codec1_name>
</phone-settings>
</settings>`

Comment: Yes, I take your point about using a new global parameter; I plan to do exactly that. My hardcode was just a quick hack to test it - this XSLT may well have to exclude other attributes.

Comment: @Nick-Gallafent: It is incorrect to ask people to modify code that's not yours in order for it to fit to your requirements. The correct thing is just to define the problem and request a solution. When the solution is received, if it doesn't fit some unforeseen new requirement, then ask a new question.

Comment: understood, I am just reluctant to ask a very similar question with a new specific.xml. As you said, the XSLT is quite complex, defining the problem is half the trouble. :)
Thank you for the pointer, I will spend some more time on this unexpected behaviour myself before asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With other approach (identify elements by name and key attributes), this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pSpecific" select="document('specific.xml')"/>
    <xsl:key name="kElemByName-Attr"
             match="*"
             use="concat(name(),'+',@idx,'+',@perm)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:param name="pSource" select="$pSpecific"/>
        <xsl:param name="pCopy" select="true()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$pSource">
            <xsl:variable name="vMatch"
                          select="key('kElemByName-Attr',
                                      concat(name($vCurrent),'+',
                                             $vCurrent/@idx,'+',
                                             $vCurrent/@perm))"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vMatch[$pCopy]">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCurrent[not($vMatch)]">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)]]">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$pSpecific">
                <xsl:variable name="vMatch"
                          select="key('kElemByName-Attr',
                                      concat(name($vCurrent),'+',
                                             $vCurrent/@idx,'+',
                                             $vCurrent/@perm))"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vMatch/node()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pSource" select="$vCurrent"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pCopy" select="false()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<settings>
    <phone-settings e="2">
        <language perm="RW">German</language>
        <codec1_name idx="1" perm="">0</codec1_name>
        <codec1_name idx="2" perm="">0</codec1_name>
        <codec1_name idx="1" perm="R">8</codec1_name>
    </phone-settings>
</settings>
```

Comment: @Alejandro - Thank you for the reply, however the output in your example shows a duplicated 'codec1_name idx=1'. The element name and idx value are used to identify unique configuration parameters for this application. if the element name/idx (not 'perm') match in the specific xml then they should take precedence for the merge. The value for the 'perm' attribute must also come from that element in the specific xml. I will look at your alternative XSLT in more detail and see if I can adapt it to overcome this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick Gallafent: Form your question it looks like `@perm` is part of the indentification: *"If the same element exists in both source files, but with a different 'perm' attribute, the XSLT considers it unique and a duplicate element is introduced"*. If that is no more the case, then you should strip `@perm` from the key.

Comment: @Alejandro - I think you've cracked it!
Your approach/code is much easier to understand than the original LGPL XSLT code I tried. I appreciate your effort to create it. I will test with more complex input files but it is certainly a much better base to start from. Thanks!